# How to sort parts of a numpy 2D array by second column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am currently working on a computer vision project with python and openCV.
I have a 2D numpy array like this:

```
 [100  38  18]
 [134 332  16]
 [136 200  16]
 [136 288  15]
 [138 160  17]
 [138 246  15]
 [140  76  12]
 [140 116  12]
 [142  34  14]
```

The 2D array is already sorted by the first column. This works fine. Now I need to sort pakets of 3 rows by the second column.
This is the result I need to achieve:

```
 [100  38  18]
 [136 200  16]
 [134 332  16]
 [138 160  17]
 [138 246  15]
 [136 288  15]
 [142  34  14]
 [140  76  12]
 [140 116  12]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `t = a.reshape(-1, 3, a.shape[1]); t[np.arange(len(t))[:,None],t[:,:,1].argsort()].reshape(a.shape)`. Please name the example data and provide a copyable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reshaping your data into 3d, then use for loop to sort each array and cast back into an np.array

```
np.array([sorted(i, key = lambda x: x[1]) for i in ar.reshape(3, -1, ar.shape[1])]).reshape(ar.shape)
 
array([[100,  38,  18],
       [136, 200,  16],
       [134, 332,  16],
       [138, 160,  17],
       [138, 246,  15],
       [136, 288,  15],
       [142,  34,  14],
       [140,  76,  12],
       [140, 116,  12]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just by NumPy, not looping:

```
sort_ = np.argsort(np.split(a[:, 1], a.shape[0] // 3))
# [[0 2 1]
#  [1 2 0]
#  [2 0 1]]

sort_ += np.linspace(0, a.shape[0] - 3, a.shape[0] // 3, dtype=np.int64)[:, None]
# [[0 2 1]
#  [4 5 3]
#  [8 6 7]]

a = a[sort_.ravel()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no other way than to use a loop

let `A` be your array

```py
output = np.zeros((0, 3))
for i in range(int(A.shape[0]/3)):
    output = np.vstack((output, A[3*i + np.argsort(A[3*i:3*(i+1), 1])]))
```

Note: I'm assuming that your array has a number of lines which is a multiple of 3